# How to bypass sudo

Tags: bash, sudo

I am trying to script a **non-interactive** install of Meteor (JS Framework) and part of the script prompts for sudo . I cant seem to get past it w/ my scripting skills.

The install is :  `curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh`

At a later point in the script it prompts for Sudo password.  **I want this step to fail**.  And then I can script my way around the resolution .

Note:: I cannot add the user to sudoers file, its running in a shared environment that doesnt allow my user elevated access.

Comment: You could obviate `sudo` by configuring it with a line like: `# allow script-user to run my-script as user user-with-permissions
script-user ALL = (user-with-permissions) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/scripts/my-script
`  Adding a line like that to `sudoers` will maintain the `sudo` securities; but allow a particular user to run the script with elevated permissions and no password.

Comment: @ericx OP: `I cannot add the user to sudoers file, its running in a shared environment that doesnt allow my user elevated access.` Besides which, modifying `/etc/sudoers` for a one-off install script, and adding that one-off install script to `/usr/local/bin` seems like overkill given the issue. Especially since we don't know exactly what the OP is trying to do; if he wants to do a local user install inside a chroot jail, not only would that be overkill, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Most linux programs that read a password (like sudo and ssh) don't read the password from `STDIN` but instead open `/dev/tty` directly.  This way you can't pipe the password into it.  If you detach the process from the controlling terminal then `/dev/tty` will be invalid and reading from it will fail.  Programs like [daemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/daemon.1.html) can do this.

Comment: @AdrianPronk I like the way you think, sir.

Comment: @AdrianPronk that is an interesting fact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will replace any instance of the string "sudo" (sans quotes) with "sudo -n" (sans quotes):

```
curl https://install.meteor.com | sed 's/sudo/sudo -n/g' | /bin/sh
```

From [the sudo manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

> -n' The -n (non-interactive) option prevents sudo from prompting the user for a password. If a password is required for the command to run,
>   sudo will display an error message and exit.

It's worth pointing out, however, that this **only works** if you would be prompted for a password. In other words, if you've recently run sudo, and those credentials allow you to run sudo without entering a password for 15 minutes (the default) and you run this within 15 minutes, the above command will still succeed in running sudo. Or if you are never normally prompted for a password, that will also cause success.

To invalidate the session created by recently entering sudo credentials, run `sudo -k`.
Again, from the manual:

> -k [command]
>
> When used alone, the -k (kill) option to sudo invalidates the user's cached credentials. The next time sudo is run a password
>   will be required. This option does not require a password and was
>   added to allow a user to revoke sudo permissions from a .logout file.
>   Not all security policies support credential caching.
>
> When used in conjunction with a command or an option that may require
>   a password, the -k option will cause sudo to ignore the user's cached
>   credentials. As a result, sudo will prompt for a password (if one is
>   required by the security policy) and will not update the user's cached
>   credentials.

If that doesn't work for you (if, for example, your security policy wouldn't request a password), you can try:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com | sed 's/sudo/sudo \/bin\/false/g' | /bin/sh
```

If the program sudo was running failed, sudo will fail. And from [the manpage for false](http://linux.die.net/man/1/false):

> Exit with a status code indicating failure.

...is all false does.

What this means is that, instead of running whatever command it's trying to run with sudo, it will instead run `/bin/false`, passing the name of the original program intended to be run under `sudo` as the first argument.

**NOTE:** If you actually want the entire first *line* containing a sudo call to fail, these solutions won't (necessarily) make that happen. The sudo call itself will fail, but if its arguments are created in a subshell, or there are previous commands on the same line, those will work as usual. So, if the original command were:

```
sudo exterminate "$(ls /humans)"
```

That would become:

```
sudo /bin/false exterminate "$(ls /humans)"
```

And `ls /humans` would still run. Probably obvious, and it likely doesn't matter, but just in case, I thought I'd mention.

Comment: we have a winner.

Comment: for the record, I ended up using an expect script that puts in an empty string 3 times, eventually failing out. I will upgrade to this better way.

Comment: @MikeGraf Ahh! Expect! Despite the fact that I have been mocked for liking it (as its manpage is... a bit dated... `For example, here are some things Expect can do: Cause your computer to dial you back, so that you can login without paying for the call.`), it's a fine language.

Answer (score 0):

Why not modify the script before using it :
`curl https://install.meteor.com > /tmp/script`, modify it in /tmp/script, then run it `/bin/sh /tmp/script`

Edit: Or if the password is asked, just type three times a bad password and you will be rejected

Comment: it has to be non-interactive